# my output contineously vary

Tags: verilog

```
module multiplier(prod, busy, mc, mp, clk, start);    
  output [15:0] prod;
  output busy;
  input [7:0] mc, mp;
  input clk, start;

  reg [7:0] A, Q, M;
  reg Q_1;
  reg [3:0] count;
  wire [7:0] sum, difference;

  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if (start) begin
      A <= 8'b0;
      M <= mc;
      Q <= mp;
      Q_1 <= 1'b0;
      count <= 4'b0;
    end
    else 
    begin
      case ({Q[0], Q_1})
        2'b0_1 : {A, Q, Q_1} <= {sum[7], sum, Q};
        2'b1_0 : {A, Q, Q_1} <= {difference[7], difference, Q};
       default: {A, Q, Q_1} <= {A[7], A, Q};
      endcase
      count <= count + 1'b1;
    end
  end

  alu adder (sum, A, M, 1'b0);
  alu subtracter (difference, A, ~M, 1'b1);

  assign prod = {A, Q};
  assign busy = (count < 8);

  initial 
  begin 
    $monitor($time,"prod=%b, busy==%b, mc=%b, mp=%b, clk=%b, start=%b",
                      prod, busy, mc, mp, clk, start);
  end
endmodule

module alu(out, a, b, cin);
  output [7:0] out;
  input [7:0] a;
  input [7:0] b;
  input cin;

  assign out = a + b + cin;
endmodule
```

----------------------------------testbench----------------------------------------------

```
module multi_tst_tst;
  reg clk, start;
  reg [7:0] a, b;
  wire [15:0] ab;
  wire busy;

  multiplier multiplier1 (ab, busy, a, b, clk, start);

  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    a =8'b11100000; b =8'b00100000; start = 1; #10 start = 0;
  end
  always #5 clk = !clk;

  //$strobe("ab: %d busy: %d at time=%t", ab, busy, $stime);
endmodule
```

This is code for booth multiplier My question when data a and b are available it will start multiplying and its continue if i want to check my answer i have to do #80 $stop but how can i modified my code such that when busy flag goes to zero my output must be at data line and wait for other input please give me some suggestion i am trying this till yesterday i know manually i can use $finish or $stop but i don't want that i want automatically my simulation stop and as another input available it will start again that why i use busy flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait until busy is deasserted. Something like this:

```
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    a =8'b11100000; b =8'b00100000; start = 1; 
    #10 start = 0;
    @(negedge busy); // waits until busy goes from 1 to 0
    $finish;
  end
```

For a more detailed test, testing (almost) every possible input:

```
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  for (a=8'd0;a<8'd255;a=a+1) begin
    for (b=8'd0;b<8'd255;b=b+1) begin
      start = 1;
      #10 start = 0;
      @(negedge busy); //wait until multiplier ends
      @(posedge clk);  //waits one clock cycle before moving to the next pair of numbers
    end
  end
```

end